# Show the limit of $x^{n}\cot(x)$ converges for n greater than or equal to $1$.

Tags: limits

For $f(x)=x^{n}\cot(x)$, we need to show $ \lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$ is convergent as long as $n \geq 1$. I know that $$\lim_{x \to 0} x\cot(x)=1$$ and that $$\lim_{x \to 0} x^{2}\cot(x)=\lim_{x \to 0} x^{3}\cot(x)=\cdots=0$$ but I just have no idea to how to actually show this. Can anyone give a hand?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are there any helpful rules for each individual case? If $n$ is an integer, you could try induction once you have a feeling as for why it works.

Comment: To be honest, I hadn't tried much. I was just kinda sitting there for an hour trying to come up with something. I didn't realize it was sufficient to just to apply squeeze theorem (just like for $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{sinx}{x}=1$) to show that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{sinx}=1$.

Comment: @user30625: How do you prove $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{sinx}{x}=1$ using Squeeze Theorem? For $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{sinx}{x}=0$ , I see it but not for the limit at $0$ (though the result is correct :D )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: just use the product rule for limits to establish the induction hypothesis. Once you know that $\lim_{x\to 0}x\cot x=1$,

$$\lim_{x\to 0}x^n\cot x = \left(\lim_{x\to 0}x^{n-1}\right)\left(\lim_{x\to 0}x\cot x\right).$$

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful! The underlying issue is showing that $\lim_{x \to 0} xcotx=1$. From there, everything follows wonderfully :). I mean, we know that $\lim_{x \to 0} cosx=1$. Does knowing that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{sinx}{x}=1$ (by squeeze lemma) $\implies \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{sinx}=1$?

Comment: @user30625 Yes, that is probably the most straightforward way to show that limit. I didn't go over that part in my answer because the way you phrased your question made it seem like you'd already done that part. I could edit my response to include a rigorous proof if you think you need it.

Comment: No that's fine. I understand everything now. It occurred to me soon after I read your hint. All of sudden, squeeze theorem flashed into my vision and all was good in the world! :P Just needed some verification that my logic was sound. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the limit converge, without using induction. If $2\leq n$
$$\lim_{x \to 0} x^n\cot{x}=\lim_{x \to 0} x\cdot x^{n-1}\frac{\cos{x}}{\sin{x}}=[\lim_{x \to 0}x^{n-1}\cos{x}]\cdot[\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x}{\sin{x}}]=[0^{n-1}\cos{0}]\cdot1=0$$

But this limit is $1$ if $n=1$.

Comment: I don't know why you got downvoted. Maybe the person didn't like the idea of not using induction? :X I think I fully understand the problem now. Thank you Asdrubal and thank you David for the help!